# Есть ли метод нахождения минимального обхода двумерного массива?

Tags: алгоритм

Задача состоив в том, чтобы найти минимальный обход.

```
010001
111100
101010
100010
```

Допустим 1 - грязные участки, а 0 - чистые. Человека можно поставить в любое место, и он может двигатся только по 1 му квадрату в любые направления.
Надо найти минимальный обход, тоесть человек должен убрать грязные участки за минимальный ход.

Comment: ну то есть вам надо построить граф и найти в нем кратчайший путь, который проходит через все единички?

Comment: @user352278 ваш вопрос сильно на задачу коммивояжера смахивает.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача относительно легко сводится к задаче коммивояжера.

Сначала представляем поле в виде графа. Каждая клетка в нем - вершина. Каждая вершина изначально соединена с 2, 3 или 4 соседними вершинами ребрами, вес каждого равен 1. теперь избавляемся от всех вершин, соответствующих чистым вершинам, кроме той, в которой изначально стоит человек. Это делается очень просто, мы хотим убрать вершину А, которая соединена и Б, В, Г и Д ребрами весом 1. Подготавливаем удаление ребра АБ, вместо него создаем 3 новых: БВ, БГ, и БД. Вес нового ребра вычисляется легко - БД = БА + АД. Затем создаем ребра, призванные заменить ВА - то есть ВД, ВГ и ВБ. ВБ уже было создано на прошлом шаге - новое создавать не надо, надо просто выбрать из двух то, что короче. Когда для всех ребер составлены замены - удаляем вершину А со всеми ее ребрами.

Когда все чистые вершины будут удалены(кроме то, где стоит человек изначально) получаем взвешенный граф и старую добрую задачу коммивояжера, решений которой множество, найти в гугле их не проблема